# DataGrid Columns not autosizing properly

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` control in my application:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          BorderThickness="1"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="True"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="True"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          FontSize="16"
          FontWeight="Bold"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Grid.Row="2"
          Margin="5"
          Name="PendingRowsGrid"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ToolTip="Number of rows pending transmission"
          Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToHide}, Path=AdvancedSettings.RunningStandAlone, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:Dashboard}}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <cs:ExtendedTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Value.DataTypeDisplay}"
                               Header="Data Type"
                               Width="*" />
        <cs:ExtendedTextColumn Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CountConverter}, ConverterParameter='#,##0', Mode=OneWay, Path=Value.ToEoc}"
                               Header="To EOC"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Width="Auto" />
        <cs:ExtendedTextColumn Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CountConverter}, ConverterParameter='#,##0', Mode=OneWay, Path=Value.FromEoc}"
                               Header="From EOC"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Width="Auto" />
    </DataGrid.Columns
</DataGrid>
```

The first column is left aligned, and the last two columns need to be right aligned.  In addition, the right most 2 columns need to adjust their widths to fit the widest value in the column.

Here's the code for the `ExtendedTextColumn` class:

```
public class ExtendedTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "HorizontalAlignment", typeof( HorizontalAlignment ), typeof( ExtendedTextColumn ),
                                     new PropertyMetadata( HorizontalAlignment.Stretch ) );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "VerticalAlignment", typeof( VerticalAlignment ), typeof( ExtendedTextColumn ),
                                     new PropertyMetadata( VerticalAlignment.Stretch ) );

    public HorizontalAlignment HorizontalAlignment {
        get { return (HorizontalAlignment) GetValue( HorizontalAlignmentProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( HorizontalAlignmentProperty, value ); }
    }

    public VerticalAlignment VerticalAlignment {
        get { return (VerticalAlignment) GetValue( VerticalAlignmentProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( VerticalAlignmentProperty, value ); }
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement( DataGridCell cell, object dataItem ) {
        FrameworkElement element = base.GenerateElement( cell, dataItem );

        // Set the FrameworkElement's HorizontalAlignment and VeritcalAligment properties
        element.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment;
        element.VerticalAlignment   = VerticalAlignment;
        return element;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement( DataGridCell cell, object dataItem ) {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox) base.GenerateEditingElement( cell, dataItem );

        // Set the TextBox's TextAlignment and VeritcalAligment properties
        textBox.TextAlignment            = GetTextAlignment();
        textBox.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment;
        return textBox;
    }

    private TextAlignment GetTextAlignment() {
        switch ( HorizontalAlignment ) {
            case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                return TextAlignment.Center;

            case HorizontalAlignment.Left:
                return TextAlignment.Left;

            case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                return TextAlignment.Right;

            default:
                return TextAlignment.Justify;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that the two right most columns are not sized properly with the XAML shown.  I've also tried using `DataGridTemplateColumns` for the right-most two columns:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="To EOC"
                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenteredHeaderText}"
                                Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" 
                               Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CountConverter}, ConverterParameter='#,##0', Mode=OneWay, Path=Value.ToEoc}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="From EOC"
                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenteredHeaderText}"
                                Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" 
                               Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CountConverter}, ConverterParameter='#,##0', Mode=OneWay, Path=Value.FromEoc}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But these, also, do not size properly.  In both cases, one to one and a half characters get cut off.  In the case of the original XAML (using the `ExtendedTextColumn` class), it's the left most character that gets cut off; in the second XAML (the `DataGridTemplateColumn` case), it's the right most character.

I've tried changing the original XAML so the `DataGrid` uses `DataGridTextColumns` for the right-most two columns and these do get sized properly.  This leads me to believe that there's something the `DataGrid` or `DataGridTextColumn` class does that isn't being done in the other two cases to determine how wide the column is, yet my `ExtendedTextColumn` class descends from `DataGridTextColumn`.  I'm at a loss.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with the Xaml & the code for most of the day, I've come up with something that almost works.

First, I stopped using my class and I used XAML similar to the following for the right two columns instead:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.FromEoc, ConverterParameter=#\,##0, Converter={StaticResource CountConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Header="From EOC"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenteredHeaderText}"
                    MinWidth="80"
                    Width="*">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I figured that since the `DataGridTextColumn` resized properly by itself that this would do the trick.  Alas, it did not.  The Column ended up being 1/2 character too narrow!

So in the end, I punted.  The original problem was that the columns were too narrow if the number of digits to be displayed was 8 or greater.  I changed the `Width` of the first column to `Auto` and the `Widths` of the last two columns to `*`.  The columns are now wide enough that I shouldn't have a problem until the number of digits is greater than 12 or so, and we shouldn't have that many digits in a production system.